# Unable to install Ubuntu on HP Envy dv4-5220us (pre-installed Windows 8)

Tags: hp, windows-8, uefi, nomodeset

I just bought a new HP Envy dv4 5220us laptop with preinstalled Windows 8. The first thing I did was format the HD remove all secure boot/UEFI options in the BIOS and - after a futile attempt at installing Windows 7 - re-installed Windows 8 Professional.

I mainly use Ubuntu (99% of the time) so it is very important for me to get it running on this pc. However, when I try running the installer for 12.10 I get the black screen issue, and if I use the "nomodeset" method, I still don't get to the installation questions. The strange thing is that when I launch the computer now, I get the choice between Windows and Ubuntu, as if it were installed (which it might be?), not in Grub, but in Windows 8, but if I select Ubuntu I go into black screen, or, with "nomodeset", it stalls after a few seconds of script.

I'm very ignorant in all these things, but I'm computer savvy, so I got to all these things by following the forums. However, I don't seem to find anything similar to the problem I'm having.

BTW - I tried to return the pc today, but because of some stupid fine print I can't, so I'M STUCK WITH IT, so I really want this to work.

Thanks,

Julian

Comment: Would it be possible for you to transfer the hard drive over to another computer and attempt to install Ubuntu from there?  I once had problems *installing* Ubuntu on a computer, but not *running* it, and this is the workaround that I used.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a win8 recovery dvd? Maybe you can go back the factory settings and try to do it again. I've installed ubuntu 12.10 and share it with  my win 8 and everything went fine.

I just had to disable the the secureboot ,create some new  partitions using gparted (from the live cd) and install ubuntu, that was all for me.

Some links that might help:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/linux-secure/files/ --> .iso with boot-repair (just in case)
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Hope it helps :)

Comment: InkBlend, I'm not sure I have the courage to attempt the HD switch, but it's a great idea, and will keep it in mind as a last resort.

Fernanda, I am downloading the iso with the boot repair, however I don't think that is the problem (since I successfully de-activated the secure boot). My problem seems to be more related to the graphic card at the moment, but I might be wrong so I'll give it a try.